# How to understand the "scanned" and "scanned_objects" in the Mongo monitor?

Tags: database, mongodb

How to understand the "scanned" and "scanned_objects" in the Mongo monitor ? I'm so confused about that. Is there anyone could do me a favor ? Thanks!

Comment: What monitoring program are you referring to and what version of MongoDB server? Can you include an example of the relevant output? I'm guessing that you are referring to some query output where `scanned` is probably the count of [index keys examined](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/#explain.executionStats.totalKeysExamined) and `scanned_objects` is the number of [documents examined](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/#explain.executionStats.totalDocsExamined).

Comment: One measure of query efficiency is the number of index keys that need to be examined in order to return a result set. If more index keys or documents are examined than returned, there is potentially room for improvement.

Comment: My monitoring program is Grafana, and the version of my MongoDB server is 3.4.0.It seams that you are right.But, i'm new here, so i could not upload pictures.I found [this](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/check-your-query-and-index-performance-with-the).And it seems like you said.Thanks for your help.